# How to logout session in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, session, firefox

I have issues on our .NET website using Firefox, after using Session.Remove() and redirecting to Home.aspx whenever you go back the user is still logged in but whenever the page is refreshed it is successfully logged out. The issue is only on Firefox browser, on google chrome whenever you go back it will automatically redirect you to home.aspx and won't allow you to go back.

Also running JavaScript on pageload does not work as well as on the C# backend. It will only run when page is reloaded.

Is this something an issue on Firefox? Any help is really appreciated, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

check the session vals in your page load event and redirect if needed

Comment: This is what I did, it does not work when you go back but does work when you refresh the page, it works on every browser except Firefox

Comment: go back meaning? click browser back button?

Comment: yes, going back is the browser's back button